# Multiple select case SQL

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite

I have a column into a SQL DB that I'm going to update doing some calculations after have evaluated differents conditions.

For example :

```
If A > 5:
    C1 = 15
else:
    C1 = 0


If B > 7:
    C2 = 24
else:
    C1 = 37


If C < 14:
    C3 = 24
else:
    C3 = 50

Result = C1 + C2 + C3
```

A, B and C are values from other columns.

So, as I evaluate some conditions at the same time I can't use 'Case When CONDITION Then RESULT Else RESULT2 End'.

Which way is the better to solve this kind of query ? I cannot escape from using 'IF, ELSE' ?

---

### **EDIT**

I would like to do it with Python and SQL, but when I have 15 conditions to evaluate it becomes really difficult to continue with the multiple 'CASE WHEN'

```
Result = ('UPDATE DB1 SET ColumnToCalcul = '
                    '(CASE WHEN' 
                        '(SUBSTR(Partnumber, 2, 2) = "57" OR SUBSTR(Partnumber, 2, 2) = "44" OR Table1.A > 0) '
                    'THEN '
                        '(SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Column2= "DOLLAR" AND Table1.Column3 <= Table3.Diametre_max AND Table1.Diametre >= Table3.Diametre_min) '
                    'ELSE '
                        'CASE WHEN '
                            '(SUBSTR(Partnumber, 2, 2) = "49" OR SUBSTR(Partnumber, 2, 2) = "51" OR Table1.A > 57) '
                        'THEN '
                            '(SELECT Column2 FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Column2= "DOLLAR" AND Table1.Column3 <= Table3.Diametre_max AND Table1.Diametre >= Table3.Diametre_min) '
                        'ELSE '
                            'NULL '
                    'END)')
```

Comment: SELECT col_1 FROM Table_name WHERE A>5 OR B>7 OR C<14

Comment: Honestly, I don't get what is exact problem. What exactly is the pseudo-code that you've posted? Do you try to find some sql-query, or solve it using Python? Why can't you use multiple `case` statements? Could you paste actual code?

Comment: I've updated the post

Answer (score 1):

Just [register a user-defined SQL function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function) in Python:

```
def MyCalc(a, b, c):
    if a > 5:
        ...
    return 42

db.create_function("MyCalc", 3, MyCalc)

db.execute("UPDATE DB1 SET ColumnToCalcul = MyCalc(ThisColumn, ThatColumn, etc);")
```

Comment: and if I do many functions, could I SUM the result of each one of them and update the column with the result of this SUM ?

Comment: This function behaves like any other function.